# Relationship between constant term and roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Does anyone know of a relationship between the constant term of a polynomial and the roots of the polynomial? Specifically, if we know the constant term, is it possible for a root which divides the constant to be a root of the polynomial? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Rational Root Theorem is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac10/fac10.html

The most important part is written slightly lower on the page:

> Suppose $P(x)=a_nx^n + \dots + a_0$
>
> is a polynomial with integer coefficients, and 
>   $x=\frac pq$ is a rational zero of $P(x)$. Then
>   $p$ divides $a_0$ and $q$ divides $a_n$